# Could NOT find LibCrypto (missing: LibCrypto_LIBRARY LibCrypto_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cmake

This is a follow up to:

- [Building the AWS SDK from source on Amazon Linux 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67335322/building-the-aws-sdk-from-source-on-amazon-linux-2)

Based on the answer I tried again locally:

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp.git
$ cd aws-sdk-cpp
$ mkdir build
$ cmake .. -DBUILD_ONLY=core -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/install
$ make install -i
```

I was forced to use `'-i'` because at least one test is failing (seems like `'make test'` rule is inside `'make all'`).

then from my pet project:

```
% cat ../CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(lambda-example)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

# Locate the aws sdk for c++ package.
find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED COMPONENTS lambda)

# The executables to build.
set(EXAMPLES "")
list(APPEND EXAMPLES "main")

# The executables to build
foreach(EXAMPLE IN LISTS EXAMPLES)
  add_executable(${EXAMPLE} ${EXAMPLE}.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(${EXAMPLE} ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES})
endforeach()
```

I get:

```
% cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=~/install
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found AWS SDK for C++, Version: 1.9.18, Install Root:/home/mathieu/install, Platform Prefix:, Platform Dependent Libraries: pthread;crypto;ssl;z;curl
-- Components specified for AWSSDK: lambda, application will be depending on libs: aws-cpp-sdk-lambda;aws-cpp-sdk-core;aws-crt-cpp;aws-c-auth;aws-c-cal;aws-c-common;aws-c-compression;aws-c-event-stream;aws-c-http;aws-c-io;aws-c-mqtt;aws-c-s3;aws-checksums;pthread;crypto;ssl;z;curl
-- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-core
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found LibCrypto: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
-- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
-- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
-- LibCrypto Static Lib:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find LibCrypto (missing: LibCrypto_LIBRARY LibCrypto_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /home/mathieu/install/lib/s2n/cmake/modules/FindLibCrypto.cmake:61 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
  /home/mathieu/install/lib/aws-c-cal/cmake/aws-c-cal-config.cmake:7 (find_dependency)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
  /home/mathieu/install/lib/aws-c-io/cmake/aws-c-io-config.cmake:8 (find_dependency)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
  /home/mathieu/install/lib/aws-c-http/cmake/aws-c-http-config.cmake:3 (find_dependency)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
  /home/mathieu/install/lib/aws-crt-cpp/cmake/aws-crt-cpp-config.cmake:3 (find_dependency)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
  /home/mathieu/install/lib/cmake/aws-cpp-sdk-core/aws-cpp-sdk-core-config.cmake:2 (find_dependency)
  /home/mathieu/install/lib/cmake/AWSSDK/AWSSDKConfig.cmake:305 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/mathieu/workspace/junk/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/mathieu/workspace/junk/bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The above is based on the reading of the following:

1. [Building the SDK from source on EC2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/wiki/Building-the-SDK-from-source-on-EC2)
2. [How to run any programming language on AWS Lambda: Custom Runtimes.](https://www.proud2becloud.com/how-to-run-any-programming-language-on-aws-lambda-custom-runtimes/)
3. [C++ Code Samples for AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-cpp-example_code-lambda.html)

The error message seems to contradict itself:

```
-- Found LibCrypto: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
[...]
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find LibCrypto (missing: LibCrypto_LIBRARY LibCrypto_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm experiencing exactly the same issue as you have described.

When using AWS SDK for C++ version 1.9.27 (checked out from the tag),

the only way I could manage to build my application under CentOS 7 environment is the next cmake command:

```
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DLibCrypto_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include -DLibCrypto_LIBRARY=/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so ..
 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
 -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - works
 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
 -- Detecting C compile features
 -- Detecting C compile features - done
 -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
 -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - works
 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
 -- Detecting CXX compile features
 -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
 -- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.27.1") 

..............
..............
..............

 -- Found Python: /usr/bin/python3.6 (found version "3.6.8") found components: Interpreter 
 -- Looking for pthread.h
 -- Looking for pthread.h - found
 -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
 -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
 -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
 -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
 -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
 -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
 -- Found Threads: TRUE  
 -- Found AWS SDK for C++, Version: 1.9.27, Install Root:/usr, Platform Prefix:, Platform Dependent Libraries: pthread;crypto;ssl;z;curl
 -- Components specified for AWSSDK: s3;s3-crt;core;transfer;iam;sts;identity-management, application will be depending on libs: aws-cpp-sdk-s3-crt;aws-cpp-sdk-transfer;aws-cpp-sdk-iam;aws-cpp-sdk-identity-management;aws-cpp-sdk-cognito-identity;aws-cpp-sdk-s3;aws-cpp-sdk-sts;aws-cpp-sdk-core;aws-crt-cpp;aws-c-auth;aws-c-cal;aws-c-common;aws-c-compression;aws-c-event-stream;aws-c-http;aws-c-io;aws-c-mqtt;aws-c-s3;aws-checksums;pthread;crypto;ssl;z;curl
 -- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-core
 -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
 -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
 -- Found LibCrypto: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include
 -- LibCrypto Shared Lib:  
 -- LibCrypto Static Lib:  
 -- Found aws-cpp-sdk-core
 -- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-sts
 -- Found aws-cpp-sdk-sts
 -- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-s3
 -- Found aws-cpp-sdk-s3
 -- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-cognito-identity
 -- Found aws-cpp-sdk-cognito-identity
 -- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-identity-management
 -- Found aws-cpp-sdk-identity-management
 -- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-iam
 -- Found aws-cpp-sdk-iam
 -- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-transfer
 -- Found aws-cpp-sdk-transfer
 -- Try finding aws-cpp-sdk-s3-crt
 -- Found aws-cpp-sdk-s3-crt
 -- Configuring done
 -- Generating done
 -- Build files have been written to: /home/user/project/path/build
```

As you can notice, there is a bunch of the weird output lines about `LibCrypto Include Dir: /usr/include`. I suppose there is the issue in AWS SDK cmake build configurations around using cmake cache variables for libcrypto stuff. After the above configuration command, I can successfully `make -j4` and `make install` my targets.

Version of cmake I used is `3.17.5`. GCC version is in the above output.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me after installing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev uuid-dev zlib1g-dev libpulse-dev
```

from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup-linux.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the libcrypto, libssl and libcurl.

I had solved the same issue in my Ubuntu machine by running the following commands.

`sudo apt-get install libcurl4`

`sudo apt-get install libcurlpp-dev`

`sudo apt-get install libcrypto++-dev`

Refer: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp#other-dependencies

Answer (score -1):

you need to install libssl-dev

```bash
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```